# Layout problems on Samsung Galaxy Y S5360

Tags: java, android, layout

I am new to Android Development. I have recently developed an app that supports Screen sizes of 3" to 4"! The problem is that When I run my app on my HTC Wildfire S (3.2") it works find the screen visuals are fine to see and it gives best resolution.

But when I run the same app on my  Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 (3") a small portion of the screen vanishes at the spot I mean the screen visuals are not so much visible to see and gives bad visuals of screen.

Why it is so when I have set the screen size as ranging from 3" to 4". I am using Relative Layout and in the Eclipse IDE the Screen is showing so well also.
HERE is the Eclipse IDE image[image]

HERE is my  Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 Image: sorry for poor image.[image]
YOU can see the problem of text at the bottom of cell phone image how can i fix this? please help thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First-  never trust the eclipse plugin.  Its buggy, and its an estimation anyway.  You can use it to see if you're roughly right, but never expect it to look like that ont he actual device, much less on all devices.

As for your problem-  the screen on your device is too small for your layout.  You either need to cut out whitespace or shrink something.  If you can find out the exact resolution of this device you could make a special layout for devices of that resolution.

This is a standard problem in android UI design-  you're developing for a lot of screen, some of which are very small.  If you want it to work on everything, you have to be very careful with the amount of content and empty space on each screen and test against a variety of resolutions and physical sizes.

A good way to get around this is to size everything in dp.  1dp=1/160th of an inch.  Then you know how big a screen you'll show on.

Comment: Also, in your case you could consider using a fullscreen theme and losing the titlebar and iconbar at top.  That would probably give you the needed size.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 suggestions are as below
1.Can you try using scroll view for your content
2. apply full screen to your app & change the current layout of the app(if in case of linear layout)